# Getting ZeroDivisionError on matplotlib _layoutgrid grid_constraints

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've been working with my code with no problem for a couple of years, but everything has changed once I decided to update matplotlib (which I need to have the latest version to be compatible with another library that I'm using).

Recently I faced a strange problem in which when using `figurecanvasTkagg.draw()` I get a `ZeroDivisionError`

It specifically says that it crashed while performing `h0 = h / self.height_ratios[0]` in the `grid_constraints` method of `matplotlib/_layoutgrid.py`

Here is the message error I get when executing the draw() function:

`line 247, in grid_constraints h0 = h / self.height_ratios[0] ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`

This is a simplification of the code that leads to this:

```
self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100, layout='constrained')
self.__plot = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
self.__plot.set_xlim(datetime.strptime('01/05/' + year + '00:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'), datetime.strptime('01/12/' + year + ' 00:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')) 
self.__plot.invert_yaxis()

cf = self.__plot.contourf(df_datetime, -depths, df.values.T, 256, extend='both', cmap='RdYlBu_r', levels=levels2)

self.__cb = plt.colorbar(cf, ax=self.__plot, label='Temperature (ºC)', ticks=levels)
self.__cbexists = True
self.__plot.set(ylabel='Depth (m)',
title=historical.split('_')[4] + ' year ' + year) 
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()
self.__plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
self.__plot.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
# Sets the x axis on the top
self.__plot.xaxis.tick_top()
# Sets the ticks only for the whole depths, the ones from the file
tick_depths = [-i for i in depths if i.is_integer()]
self.__plot.set_yticks(tick_depths) self.canvas.draw()
```

There is nothing I can actually change as this method is well inside the library and I have found no way to access it or modify it. I've tried searching for days for the solution to this error but I've found nothing.

When creating my figure I do have selected the layout parameter to be constrained to avoid getting one of the axes crushed to zero but it seems like it keeps happening anyways.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please add the code snippet which leads you to this error?

Comment: @AjeetVerma edited the question to add an snippet of the code.